# Current and conductance from the Landauer formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-current, landauers-principle

The Landauer formula for a one dimensional quantum system (potential step scattering) can be written as

$$
I(V)=\frac{2e}{h}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dE T(E) (f_S(E) - f_D(E)),
$$

where $T(E)$ is the transmission probability and $f_i(E)$ is the Fermi function of source $S$ or drain $D$. In [Cuevas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9813226021) it is claimed that if the temperature is zero (Fermi functions are potential steps) and if low voltages is assumed, the expression reduces to

$$
I = GV,
$$

where the conductance is given by $G=(2e^2/h)T$.

What is the low voltages assumption? In other words, if I assume low voltages, along with zero temperature, what is left to compute in the integral?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the relationship $I(V)$ for arbitrary voltages is nonlinear in the voltage difference $V$, and the assumption of low voltage allows one to write the linear approximation $I \approx GV$ by expanding at first order the difference of the Fermi-Dirac functions.

At zero temperature, the relationship $I(V)$ is still nonlinear unless $T(E)$ is a constant independent of $E$.